# Ask before applying automatic migration

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

If my database version is out of date, I want my demo win-forms application to ask the user whether to apply an automatic migration.

I see from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj591621.aspx) that automatic migration is controlled by

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true  // or false
```

inside the Migrations Configuration class.

so I could put a MessageBox at this point, however I only want to ask if the version is out of date.

I could query

```
context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true)
```

to find out whether the model needs upgrading, however I don't know how to get access to the context from within the Configuration initializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used error handling to figure out whether to ask to run the database update.

In my context I put

```
public class MyAppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyAppDbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        if (!Database.Exists())

        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MyAppDbInitializerCreateIfNotExists());
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The database is not compatible with the entity model.");
            }
        }
    }

    public MyAppDbContext() // used for migrations
        : base("name=ApplicationDatabase")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyAppDbInitializerCreateIfNotExists());
    }

    public MyAppDbContext(bool forceMigration) // used for migrations
        : base("name=ApplicationDatabase")
    {
        if (forceMigration)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyAppDbContext, Configuration>());
        }
    }

    public bool SanityCheck()
    {
        try
        {
            var rec = JobLists.Select(x => x.Id == 1);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }

// the rest of the class
}
```

in my program I put

```
 static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {

       /// some set up code missing here
        MyAppWindowsFormsApplication winApplication = new MyAppWindowsFormsApplication();

        try
        {
            winApplication.Setup();
            winApplication.Start();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.InnerException.Message == "The database is not compatible with the entity model.")
            {
                var msg = new StringBuilder();
                msg.AppendLine("The database structure has changed.");
                msg.AppendLine("Do you want to upgrade the database structure. (Say no and call support if you are unsure)");
                if (MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString(), "Upgrade database", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    var o = new MyAppDbContext(true);
                    o.SanityCheck();
                    MessageBox.Show("Database has been upgraded");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                  winApplication.HandleException(e); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It could be fixed to not rely on the InnerException Message strings matching.